# Oracle APEX Dynamic Actions locks page

Tags: javascript, multithreading, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a dynamic action in Oracle APEX PAGE, that executes PL/SQL CODE (a stored procedure that creates a BLOB)

So when the users clicks on it, the javascript behind (dynamic actions, 'runs' the PL and the page is 'locked' until everything finishes)

How can I make something that doesn't lock the browser entirely until this process is finished?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straight-forward way, if you haven't moved to version 5 yet is to use the [`APEX_PLSQL_JOB` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_plsql_job.htm).

Define the functionality you need inside the database, in a function or procedure in a package.

Then, start the function in the background using the API.

For example, if you have defined a procedure `upload_pending` inside a package `PROJECTX_IO`, then you can start it with:

```
declare
  p_job number
begin
p_job := apex_plsql_job.submit_process(
    p_sql => 'BEGIN PROJECTX_IO.upload_pending; END;',
    p_status => 'Uploading');
end;
```

You are currently not doing anything with the job id returned in `p_job`. What works, if you know you only have a single background job running at any time, is to add it to a one-row table in the database. This simply goes to the bottom of the code snippet above (before the `end;`):

```
delete from t_job;
insert into t_job values ( p_job );
```

Then, inside the background process, you have access to the job id of the process. You could change the job status at the end with:

```
select job into p_job from t_job;
apex_plsql_job.update_job_status(p_job,
    'Upload complete');
```

How to deal with multiple background jobs?

Comment: The APEX_PLSQL_JOB package is deprecated. Recommend DBMS_SCHEDULER instead.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thank you for the hint